# ng-packagr and shared modules

Tags: angular5, umd, ng-packagr

I'm trying to package a module X with dependencies to Y using ng-pacakgr.
X and Y have services and components.

App/module structure is :

- ModuleX imports ModuleY
- X.forRoot() provides ServiceY.
- ServiceY is used in AppModule and ModuleX.
- AppModule imports both modules X.forRoot() and Y.forRoot().

> ```
> AppModule
>   - ModuleY
>       - ServiceY
>   - ModuleX
>       - ServiceX
>       - ModuleY
>         - ServiceY
> ```

Packaging ModuleX with ng-packagr tells me this :

> No name was provided for external module 'Y' in options.globals – guessing 'Y'

OK

Running the app doesn't give any error, but it seems I have two instance of ServiceY.

Looking at webpack sources in chrome, i have ServiceY twice :

```
- webpack://
  - ./node_modules/Y/src/y.service.js
  - pathToX/node_modules/Y/src/y.service.js
```

positionning breakpoint in both ServiceY's constructors show it is stopping in both classes.

**In theory ServiceY should be instanced once in my whole application since ServiceY is provided at the root of the app**

I tried to add the option umdModuleIds with various values but it doesn't look to make a difference.

In conclusion, I have two unique instance of ServiceY (one being imported by app, the other imported (and redefined) by X).

Questions are :

- where is taht comming from.
- how can I be sure Y is instanciated only once in my app.
- what should I configure in umdModuleIds (how do I find moduleId)

Thanks.

#### Version Information

```
ng-packagr: 2.4.2
@angular/*: 5.2.9
typescript: ~2.4.2
rxjs: 5.5.8
node: 6.10.3
npm: 3.10.10
```